# Android studio enable method suggestions and jump to method definitions [NDK perspective]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-ndk

AndroidStudio doesn't seem to have any of the coding assistance (method suggestions, jump to method definitions etc) for native C code that it provides for Java. How do I turn this on ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. However, a lot of people have been complaining about such problems. See if any of the following helps:

1. Invalidate cache: Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
2. Make sure Power Save Mode on File menu is disabled
3. Go to File > Settings. Look for Inspections - ensure that Android and Android Lint is checked, or alternately just set it back to default. 
   Also, search for Code Completion - ensure the Auto-insert options and Autopopup code completion option is checked